# Does System.out.println support multiple arguments?

Tags: java

```
public class Book
{
    String bookName;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Book Object = new Book();
        Object.bookName = "Network Technology Design";
        System.out.println("The book named", Object.bookName);
    }
}
```

As you see, the

```
System.out.println("The book named", Object.bookName);
```

is wrong,but if I do that

```
  System.out.println(Object.bookName);
```

No any error, why?

Comment: change to this: System.out.println("The book named"+Object.bookName);

Comment: Very good,Thanks but the book tell me + also can use,

Comment: I think this question shouldn't receive so many downvotes. The format is good, and OP did try something but doesn't understand why. For a newbie to a programming language it's difficult to know what exactly needed to search for a simple question, because everyone assume you already know that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to concatenate the Strings with a "+", because System.out.println() only takes one parameter.

You have to do it like this:

```
System.out.println("The book named " + Object.bookName);
```

Comment: @DeSI You should accept the best answer

Answer (score 2):

If you see the [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) class,then you can find that there are no such method println which accepts 2 arguments.

So
`System.out.println("The book named", Object.bookName);` is wrong and `System.out.println(Object.bookName);` is right

Comment: accept the best answer

Answer (score 2):

System.out.println expected String, and you try to pass additional paramters. As menthioned in comments, use string concatenation or foramt function

```
System.out.println(String.format("The book named %s", Object.bookName))
```

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println() takes only one parameter - Any primitive data type or Object type. Need to make it one argument by concatenating or combining..!

Answer (score 0):

PrintStream class overloading`println()` method depending on arguments type it call the method and it have *only one argument or no argument*.

like `println(), println(String x), println(int x)` etc